# SQL Server 2008 add column as identity to existing table

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, identity

I'd need to add a column to an existing table. this column has to be added at the END of the table and must be an increasing integer. (identity).

Can it be done on an existing table? if so how?

Basically I am transferring this table and need to read it. to do so i am using this query:

```
select * 
from (select 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() over (order by localcol desc) as RowId 
      from " & i & ") dt 
where 
    RowId between  " & currentrow & " and " & currentrow + TextBox7.Text
```

but this requires too much memory and the PLC this is running on hangs since the table has 3.000.000 rows.

Since this has to be done only one in a while I was thinking to add an `identity` column, execute the query using this column for the range, and at the end remove the column again..

Comment: Yes, an `identity` column will give you this functionality - but adding it to an existing large table won't be *instantaneous* - it, too, will take its time! So then ***WHY*** do you want to remove it at the end?? Doesn't make any sense - if you have it in place - leave it! Make use of it!

Comment: Is `" & i & "` a table name?

Comment: i dont care if it takes time, because i am transferring this table, thats why i have to read each row. when its transferred i need it to be exactly the same as it was before or it wont be compatible with the program that generated the table in the first place... yes i is a table name

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  Just create a new table using CREATE TABLE and specify your existing columns. Then add 1 more that is an identity.  Insert your data into this new table, do what ever processing you need to do, then delete the table using DROP TABLE.

You can do the same thing with a temp table too, your choice.